# Nextjs getstaticpaths in build time tries to render un existing paths

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, getstaticpaths

Now this is my situation:

My file structure:

[image]

My UI structure:

[image]

So, when i access the routes outside "Folder 1" ( `[docsSlug].js` ) (Home, Article 1, Article 2, ...) they work fine but when i go inside the folder on "Catch All Routes" ( `[...subDocsSlug].js` ) they work fine until i refresh the page. When i refresh the page it gives me error that something is `undefined`.
When i try to `build` the project i see that it tries to generate some paths which are inside "Folder 1" but without the `/folder-1/` path segment.
for example it tries to generate these paths:

```bash
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /docs/[...subDocsSlug]: /docs/art-inside-folder-1
    /docs/[...subDocsSlug]: /docs/art-inside-folder-2
    /docs/[...subDocsSlug]: /docs/article-inside-3
```

while the correct path is `/docs/folder-1/art-inside-folder-1`.
Please note that it also renders the correct paths but it tries to render these wrong ones additionally.

This is my GraphQL query:

```
export const DOCS = gql`
  query {
    docArticles(sort: "customSort") {
      data {
        attributes {
          Title
          Slug
          AdditionalDocs {
            Title
            Slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

and this is my getStaticPaths code in the `[...subDocsSlug].js` file:

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: DOCS,
  });

  const docs = data?.docArticles?.data;

  const paths = docs.map((path) => {
    return path.attributes.AdditionalDocs.map((subPath) => {
      
      return { params: { subDocsSlug: [subPath.Slug] } }
    });
  });

  const mergedPaths = paths.flat(1);

  return {
    paths: mergedPaths || null,
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```

What am i doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated!